With Ansible, receive an email when a machine does not respond to ping
I am trying to set up a playbook that allows me to receive an email when a machine in my inventory does not respond to a ping.
The Playbook:
- name:
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Test ping
    ansible.builtin.ping:
    register: ping_result
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Send email
    community.general.mail:
      host: smtp.office365.com
      port: 587
      username: *@email*
      password: *password*
      from: *@email*
      to: admin <*@email*>
      subject: 'Network Monitoring Alert.'
      body: "The server {{ inventory_hostname }} is not responding."
      secure: starttls
    when: ping_result.failed`

Does the fact that it is unreachable via SSH prevent the ping task from being executed, and therefore the email task subsequently?

All machines respond to ping requests
It works very well if I remove the condition (so no SMTP side issues).

However, when I change an IP (and that I re-add the condition), I do not receive any emails (even though I am supposed to receive one).


Does the fact that it is unreachable via SSH prevent the ping task from being executed, and therefore the email task subsequently?

Yes, obviously that seems to be the case according an example output for such a playbook
TASK [SSH ping] ***********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test.example.com]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname test.example.com: Name or service not known'
  unreachable: true
fatal: [test.example.net]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host test.example.net port 22: Connection timed out'
  unreachable: true

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
test.example.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test.example.net : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

The play ends for any host which is unreachable: true and no further task will become executed. So even unreachable test – Did task end due to the host was unreachable won't help in your example, but together with Ignoring unreachable host errors, a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: SSH ping
    ping:
    register: result
    ignore_unreachable: true

  - assert:
      that:
        - not result is unreachable
      success_msg: "Host was reachable."
      fail_msg: "Host wasn't reachable!"

will result into an output of
TASK [SSH ping] ***********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test.example.net]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname test.example.net: Name or service not known'
  unreachable: true
...ignoring
fatal: [test.example.com]: UNREACHABLE! => changed=false
  msg: 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host test.example.com port 22: Connection timed out'
  unreachable: true
...ignoring

TASK [assert] *************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: not result is unreachable
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Host wasn't reachable!
fatal: [test.example.net]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: not result is unreachable
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Host wasn't reachable!

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
test.example.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
test.example.net : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1


Thank you first of all for your response which was well explained. However, it has been several days that I am still trying. All the tasks after the "unreachable: true" are skipped. Only the assert module is working well.
